# Do browsers delete resources with POST requests?

Tags: django, post, http-delete

I have found this snippet in the [django codebase](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L216):

```
# Add support for browsers which only accept GET and POST for now.
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What does this mean? Do browsers delete resources with `GET` / `POST` requests? Why? Can somebody provide a rationale / history / link for why this might be so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Answer (score 0):

It's for `django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView`. Your code is from `DeletionMixin`, and `DeleteView` inherit this mixin for delete object.

here's `self.delete()` code

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect to the
    success URL.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

You can check about `DeleteView` in docs ([here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi5-KK4rPPbAhVMF4gKHXzsCyAQygQILDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.djangoproject.com%2Fen%2F2.0%2Fref%2Fclass-based-views%2Fgeneric-editing%2F%23deleteview&usg=AOvVaw3rIrVr_o-ujMTStCzeatVa)).

Basically, `DeleteView` receive both `get` and `post` for deleting object. That's why

Comment: Sure, but why? Why would I want to delete an object with a POST or GET request? We have an specific DELETE method